# How to count special sets?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ objects. How many subsets are there such that  $T_1,T_2,T_3$ are three subsets of $S$ such that $T_1 \subseteq T_2 \subseteq T_3$ ?

To me it looks like for two sets such that $T_1 \subseteq T_2$ is  :

$n\choose 0  $ $2^{n}+$ $n\choose 1$ $2^{n-1} +..... $

Comment: Do they need be strictly contained, or can they be equal?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri equals are allowed

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Without loss of generality, let $S=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,n\}$

Consider the function $f(x)~:~S\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ defined as $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~x\in T_1\\2&\text{if}~x\in T_2\setminus T_1\\ 3&\text{if}~x\in T_3\setminus T_2\\4&\text{if}~x\in S\setminus T_3\end{cases}$

Confirm that $f$ truly is a function and consider what it has to do with your problem.

Comment: Do I need to count number of such functions to solve the original question.

Comment: @ddddd yes, that is where the hint is leading you to.

Comment: As an aside, the question of "*what if the sets do need to be strictly contained in one another?*" is relatively interesting.  Approach similarly, but we would be interested in an almost surjective function (*don't care if $1$ or $4$ have a preimage*).  Just as in the case of deriving the formula for the number of surjective functions, apply inclusion-exclusion to arrive at an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Such a configurations partitions $S$ into $4$ (not necessarily non-empty) parts: $T_1$, $T_2\setminus T_1$, $T_3\setminus T_2$ and $S\setminus T_3$.
We can hence associate to any such configuration a unique assignment of each $k \in S$ to one of the $4$ parts.

It follows that there are $4^n$ such configurations.

EDIT: Oh well, guess I spoiled JMoravitz's answer.